# dealloc doesn't work in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, dealloc, xcode

i have game with cocos2d and method dealloc
i use this to change scene.

```
CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
CCMoveTo* move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:CGPointMake(-(size.width), 0)];
CCEaseBackInOut* ease = [CCEaseBackInOut actionWithAction:move];
CCCallFunc* func = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(changeScene:)];
CCSequence* sequence = [CCSequence actions:ease, func, nil];
[self runAction:sequence];
```

or this in another scene.

```
CCScene* scene = [levelScene scene];
[userName removeFromSuperview];
CCTransitionFlipAngular *transitionScene=[CCTransitionFlipAngular transitionWithDuration:1 scene:scene];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:transitionScene];
```

whene i changing scene the dealloc method doesn't do anything and onExit method too.
where i can releas my pointers ?or i have and constants wnat to equal to 0 when change scene.
whene i can do it?or why i can use dealloc.

Answer (score 1):

dealloc is only called on an object when the memory management system determines that the object is no longer in use, when the retain count goes to zero.  What are you doing to cause that to happen?  I don't see any release or autorelease methods in your code samples.

You're going to have to be more specific about what you're doing to change scenes for a better answer.

Comment: this is my dealloc
-(void) dealloc
{
 
 [gameImages release];
 [spritesImages release];
 [usersNames release];
 [usersScores release];
 [lifes release];
 canTouch=0;
 opensCount=0;
 gameOver=0;
 score=0;
 x=1;
 CCLOG(@"dealloc: %@", self);
 [super dealloc];
}//dealloc
what is method work whene Scene changed?or scene run?

Comment: Your dealloc code looks reasonable, but there's no reason to set those values to zero since that object is going away anyway.

Comment: However, dealloc won't get called unless something is causing that object to be released.  What are you doing to cause that object to be released?

Comment: nothing.
whene i change scene, that mean the objects in this scene must be deleted.

Comment: Then you're going to have to release the scene object yourself.  iOS doesn't know that you're not planning on reusing the object.  There's no automated garbage collection in iOS.

Comment: and what is method where i can release my object??
in changescene Method?

Comment: Wherever it is that you determine you're done with the previous scene.  changeScene sounds like an appropriate place.  This is my last comment.  If you still have problems, ask a new question.